# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000] tcolorbox error

Tags: tcolorbox, preamble

I'm trying to make a document using boxes made with `tcolorbox` but I keep on getting this error at the end of my second box definition.  It's especially weird because this code is literally copy-pasted from another one of my projects and I wanted to use the same box setups.

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most, many, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{theorembg}{RGB}{252, 242, 245}
\definecolor{shadowcol}{RGB}{128, 128, 128}
\definecolor{bluegrad}{RGB}{0, 16, 190}
\definecolor{redgrad}{RGB}{143, 0, 48}
\definecolor{titlecol}{RGB}{220, 43, 27}
\definecolor{greengrad}{RGB}{3, 191, 0}
\definecolor{yellowgrad}{RGB}{191, 191, 0}
\definecolor{defbg}{RGB}{255, 254, 249}
\definecolor{seccol}{RGB}{33, 18, 59}
\definecolor{mybluecolor}{RGB}{1,14,122}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems, skins, hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{theorem}{Theorem}
{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback = theorembg,
    drop shadow = shadowcol,
    frame style = {left color=bluegrad, right color=redgrad},
    rounded corners,
    detach title,
    coltitle = titlecol,
    before upper = \tcbtitle\par\smallskip,
    fonttitle = \scshape,
    description font = \bfseries,
    description delimiters parenthesis,
    separator sign none}
{th}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems, skins, hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{definition}{Definition}
{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback = defbg,
    frame style = {left color=greengrad, right color=yellowgrad},
    rounded corners,
    detach title,
    coltitle = titlecol,
    before upper = \tcbtitle\par\smallskip,
    fonttitle = \scshape,
    separator sign none,
}{th}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems, skins, hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{proposition}{Proposition}
{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback = theorembg,
    drop shadow = shadowcol,
    frame style = {left color=bluegrad, right color=redgrad},
    rounded corners,
    detach title,
    coltitle = titlecol,
    before upper = \tcbtitle\par\smallskip,
    fonttitle = \scshape,
    description font = \bfseries,
    description delimiters parenthesis,
    separator sign none,
}{th}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems, skins, hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{propanddef}{Proposition and Definition}
{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback = defbg,
    frame style = {left color=greengrad, right color=yellowgrad},
    rounded corners,
    detach title,
    coltitle = titlecol,
    before upper = \tcbtitle\par\smallskip,
    fonttitle = \scshape,
    separator sign none,
}{th}

\newcommand{\thm}[2]{\begin{theorem}{#1}{} \itshape#2 \end{theorem}}
\newcommand{\dfn}[2]{\begin{definition}{#1}{} \itshape#2 \end{definition}}
\newcommand{\prop}[2]{\begin{proposition}{#1}{} \itshape#2  \end{proposition}}
\newcommand{\propdef}[2]{\begin{propanddef}{#1}{} \itshape#2 \end{propanddef}}
```

Here is an example of how I apply the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\input{preamble}

\title{\Huge\textbf{Testing Testing \\ Testing}}
\date{\large \today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

If it can be of any help, I'm using Overleaf.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem, so people can debug. You have posted a lot of code but not in a form anyone can use to see your problem